# Display custom popup for a user only once on browser/tab close OR Display popup when user hover on browser bar or close button

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, css, asp.net

My purpose is directly show the custom popup which I want to display to the user of my website on browser/tab/window close. How to track browser/tab close? I have used onbeforeunload() method but it is showing me leave/stay message. I don't want to display that message to user. Is there any other way to track if user has hover on browser bar or browser close button ? Any help would be highly appreciated!

```
<div id="promocode_popup" class="popup hide" runat="server">
<p class="popupText2">Enter your email to receive Promocode</p>
<strong class="strongText">10% OFF!</strong>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:LinkButton ID="btn_Submit" runat="server" OnClick="btn_Submit_OnClick" >Send Coupon!</asp:LinkButton>
</div>



 <script type="text/javascript">   
    window.onbeforeunload = function () {
        Unhide('promocode_popup');       
        return "hi";
    };
</script>
```

Comment: No. `onbeforeunload` fires *every* time the page is unloaded, no matter how that comes to happen. There's no way to differentiate what caused the event.

Comment: Is there any way to check if user has done mouse hover on browser bar or close button?

Comment: No. JS can only track events that occur in the DOM. The close button is part of the OS UI which is not in scope

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is **NO**. 
You have to respect the user decision of leaving the page. The message the browser displays can't be cosmetized.